# How to style td's that are selecting MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to work out how I can style the td's in the following code.

I want the Match Details to be aligned to the right. Normally I would just insert  straight in, but this doesn't seem to work.

I also want to bolded the away team row.

Any idea?

Cheers

```
<h3>SEPTEMBER 2017</h3>
<table><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE `year`='2017' AND `Division`='AA1' AND `month`='September'";

$result = $conn ->query($sql);
if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["day"] . ", " . $row["date"] . " " . $row["month"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["awayteam"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["homescore"] . " - " . $row["awayscore"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["venue"] . "</td> <td>ESFA League</td><td>Match details</td></tr><br>";
    }

 "</table>";
} else {
    echo "No games listed for this month";
}
?></table>
```

Comment: This code would give you an error, since there's no `echo` in front of your table closing tag. Anyways you don't want to close the table inside the while loop. I've editet it and posted it in answer section below.

Answer (score 1):

to styling your display data you need to apply css code as declared in `<style>` tag.

```
<style>
.table-boarderd{
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
}
.pull-right{
    text-align: right;
}
.bold{
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<h3>SEPTEMBER 2017</h3>
<table class="table-boarderd">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE `year`='2017' AND `Division`='AA1' AND `month`='September'";
$result = $conn ->query($sql);
?>

<?php
if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$row["day"]?></td>
            <td><?=$row["date"]?></td>
            <td><?=$row["month"]?></td>
            <td class="pull-right bold"><?=$row["awayteam"]?></td>
            <td><?=$row["homescore"]?>-<strong><?=$row["awayscore"]?></strong></td>
            <td><?=$row["venue"]?></td>
            <td>ESFA League</td>
            <td>Match details</td>
         </tr><br/>
    <?php } ?>
</table>

<?php }

else {
    echo "No games listed for this month";
}

?>
```

As I have used custom css with table **awayteam** cell you can use at anywhere

Comment: @Chris if you found this is useful accept it as answer and help others. Thanks for appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Write the css for the code in head tag

```
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: It's only the match details cell that I want aligned to the right. The rest are to be left as is.

Comment: oh..! use `style="text-align: right;"` in td formation

Answer (score 0):

Then you're trying it the false way, because the straight way in is possible. Also you've closed your table twice. I removed it once. Try this:

```
    <h3>SEPTEMBER 2017</h3>
<table><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE `year`='2017' AND `Division`='AA1' AND `month`='September'";

$result = $conn ->query($sql);

if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["day"] . ", " . $row["date"] . " " . $row["month"] . "</td> <td><b>" . $row["awayteam"] . "</b></td> <td>" . $row["homescore"] . " - " . $row["awayscore"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["venue"] . "</td> <td>ESFA League</td><td style="text-align: right;">Match details</td></tr><br>";
    }

}

else {
    echo "No games listed for this month";
}

?></table>
```